# How to check http request method using API Gateway v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-http-api

My Architecture:

- AWS HTTP API w/ reverse proxy integration
- Plain Lambda function
- Postman or browser

I'm trying to check the request method to handle actions, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55354065/api-gateway-post-method-working-during-tests-but-not-with-postman) answer they recomm

```
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    switch (event.httpMethod) {
        case 'GET':
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error(`@@@@ Unsupported method "${event.httpMethod}"`);
    }
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({message: 'Success'})
    };
};
```

I pasted that code just like that in my lambda and it doesn't work, I get this error in the logs:

```
"errorMessage": "@@@@ Unsupported method \"undefined\"",
```

That lambda is triggered by my HTTP API and the route has GET method.

If I return the event, I can see that the method is GET or POST, or whatever, look:

[image]

Anyone has any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input Object Schema for HTTP api (v2) is different to REST api (from your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55354065/api-gateway-post-method-working-during-tests-but-not-with-postman)).

For a Http api, method can be obtained from `event.requestContext.http.method`

so, it will look like this.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log('event',event);
    switch (event.requestContext.http.method) {
        case 'GET':
            console.log('This is a GET Method');
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error(`@@@@ Unsupported method "${event.httpMethod}"`);
    }
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};
```

Comment: I need some sleep, I swear at some point I tried that and didn't work. Thanks Balu

Comment: urw. must have been some typo! :)

Comment: This solved it. So, the lambda function test event is working perfectly, but when I call my public endpoint I get this error Unsupported method \"undefined\"" unless I switch to the requestContext.http.method. Question: What's the correct way to at least console.log the event object to inspect it or to test /debug the HTTP API (v2) in Lambda? Thanks